# How to tweak FOSUserBundle for an AJAX-only use?

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony on my backend, accessed only by a JS frontend with AJAX requests.

The issue I'm having is that the return codes sent by the FOSUserBundle does not coincide with what I'm expecting for 'user management' actions.

For instance, when for instance a user tries to register on the frontend :

***What I get:***

- **Registration success** --> Redirection to '.../confirmed'
- **Registration failure** --> 200 (re-displaying the form page)

***What I would like to have:***

- **Registration success** --> 202 Added
- **Registration failure** --> 500 or else

Do you know how to archieve that, especially given that, in FOSUserBundle, there are no events to hook on to for failures?

Comment: How do you define registration failure in your case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: do you want to know how a registration can fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the file `RegistrationController.php` in the path `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/`

In this file, you will find a method called `registerAction`. Simply add the following code in your form validation part.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

    $userManager->updateUser($user);

    if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

    return $response;
}
else
{
    return new JsonResponse(array('status' => 'failure'), 500);
}
```

Keep in mind this is a simple case of invalid form validation that I have provided. You can do other type of modifications in this part.

Comment: Is this a proper way to do this? I mean, isn't modifying vendor code something to avoid if possible? Would'nt it be possible to use a 'forward' from another custom user controller so that the original controller stays untouched?

Comment: Modifications happen [all the time](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+modify). It totally depends on what you want to do and which way is easier for you. I am not sure about the alternatives but I have modified vendor code several times and lived to talk about it.

Comment: @Silverspur Do you have an update for this? Did you come up with a better solution? If so you should consider writing your own answer and accepting it or accept one of the existing answers if they help you.

Comment: I ended up writing what I needed from scratch, since it was a very small subset of FOSUserBundle.

Comment: @Silverspur Then you should post your solution and accept that as an answer so that it helps future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 0):

After a few analysis, I decided to rewrite entirely what I needed from scratch, since it was a very small subset of FOSUserBundle.

This solves the problem, allowing to return specific responses with the desired HTTP codes, at any stage of the processes.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the problem.  You should post the solution you used as it may help other people with this issue.